# Kile spell check not working?

Tags: kile

I have Kile installed on my computer with Windows 10. The spell check does not appear to do anything. After selecting "Spelling", a dialogue box saying "Spell check complete" pops up. No misspelled words are ever found (even if I purposefully misspell them). I've made sure to correctly select my language.

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it.

What's going on?

The spell check in Kile works just fine on my Linux machine.